# Using arraybuffers to store canvas rendering data

Tags: javascript, canvas, arraybuffer

**Canvas Performance**

Lately i'm creating alot of animations in canvas, and as canvas has no events you need to create your own eventsystem based on the coordinates, in short you need a collisiondetection function.As most of the codes are very long i rewrote my own and doing so i undersood how simple it is. So i wrote some sort of a game code.

Basically canvas games are alot of temp arrays of numbers, where in most cases a number between 0 and 64,128 or 256 would be enough. Maybe reduced and used as a multipler

```
hitpoints=max*(number/256);
```

So i was thinking **What if i store these values into an `arraybuffer`?**

```
var array = new Float64Array(8);
array[0] = 10;
//....
```

**Example:**(i do it that way... if you know something better feel free to tell me)

```
//Usable ammonition
var ammo=[
 ['missiles',dmg,range,radius,red,green,blue,duration],
 //all appart the first are numbers between 0 and 255
 ['projectile',dmg,range,radius,red,green,blue,duration]
]
//Flying ammonition
//this is created inside the canvas animation everytime you shoot.
var tempAmmo=[
 [id,timestarted,x,y,timepassed] //these are all integers.
 // the longest is probably  the timestamp
]
// i could add the ammo numbers to the tempAmmo (which is faster):
[id,timestarted,x,y,timepassed,dmg,range,radius,red,green,blue,duration]

// then i do the same double array for enemies and flyingEnemies.
```

wouldn't it be better to store everything in arrabuffers?

What i think (correct me if i'm wrong):

`arraybuffers` are binary data,

they should be **faster** for the rendering, they should be **smaller**
 for the memory.

***Now if this two opinions are correct how do i properly create an array structure like the described one, maybe choosing the proper array Type?***

**Note:** in my case i'm using a bidimensional array.And obiovsly i don't want to use objects.

Comment: Theoretically this would also allow to record the whole game into an array that, saved later is a tiny binary file?!.

Comment: This would be best posted on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: nah .. has nothing to do how nice the code is.btw, this is an array.

Comment: Code Review is not just for readability, it is for design patterns, data structures, paradigms and even compiler tricks. Which is what I understand this question to be asking.

Comment: WTH would you use a `Float64` when you say yourself that an `Uint8` is enough? You seemed to care about memory size.

Comment: i'm registered on codereview i have some questions and answers there but this is a 100% stack question.

Comment: hei bergi ... i don't know the difference between uinit8 and float64, i mean ... prolly float64 is an array of a flotaing number of max 64 chars????

Comment: Why don't you want to use objects? They can be very fast as well. Especially your array that consits of integers *and one string* is very bad for optimisation.

Comment: if i later use much random i have to do many for in loops... i go with while. the string can also be stored int oan extra array ... that is just the name now for testing later everything is raplaced with images

Comment: Yes, it's a floating point number with 64 bits. You say however that you have "*a number between 0 and 64,128 or 256*" which (I'm assuming an integer) fits in 8 bits.

Comment: ok, so with the first array i need a Uint8 array, and for the second to store the timestamp? or evne if i want to mix floats & 256 is there some sort of matrix,mixed array ... what about 2dimensional array or maybe more?

Comment: You really should go with objects there. You've got a structure that you will never need to enumerate, and which consists of very different types (strings, dates, ints, floats).

Comment: outside the animation i could use a object. but inside the animationframe no. for every enemy flying array i need to check every missile flying... this is alot in not much time.i handle arrays ok.. no need for words.prefer numbers.

Comment: i know that the javascript is much faster , than most ppl think , i see the javascript calculation time in microseconds using window.performance.now. here is something to play with.http://jsfiddle.net/ecJpW/embedded/result/

Comment: mouse .... click,click...

Comment: was surprised that it actually renders images faster than text.if you remove the text part the js rendering time reduces from 200microseconds to 30microseconds.